# Совместимость двухбайтных символьных типов в бинарном представлении

Tags: c++, строки, 1с, unicode, типы

Есть интерфейс на C++ для т.н. [внешней компоненты](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/3221/hdoc) для 1С (Native API), в нём используются строковые литералы вида `L"string"`. Так как размер типа `wchar_t` зависит от платформы (Linux - 4 байта, Windows - 2 байта), то там же используется функция преобразования, а также макрос:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#define WCHAR_T     wchar_t
#else
#define WCHAR_T     uint16_t
#endif
```

У функций, которые используются для взаимодействия с 1С стандартный интерфейс. Все они должны передавать и принимать `WCHAR_T*`, т.е. `wchar_t*` для Windows и `uint16_t*` для Linux. Т.к. `uint16_t` всего лишь целочисленный тип, то очевидно, что проблем с ним быть не может.

Я задумался над тем, чтобы просто заменить `L"string"` на `u"string"` и избавиться от лишних преобразовний. Но не вполне ясно, насколько бинарно совместимы типы `wchar_t` и `char16_t`?

Вроде как 1С использует UTF-16, и тип `char16_t` был создан для него же...
Могут ли быть с этим проблемы, пускай даже не конкретно в этом случае, а вообще, между заменой старого `wchar_t` на более новый `char16_t`?

Comment: `Так как размер типа wchar_t зависит от платформы (Linux - 4 байта, Windows - 2 байта), то там же используется функция преобразования` т.е. у вас есть спец. функция для преобразования `wchar_t`- литералов в `WCHAR_T*`?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл. Да, но она не у меня, она в прмиере есть. И весь код на неё завязан. Код кривой.

Comment: Но если вы будете использовать литералы типа `char16_t`, то функция преобразования всё равно будет нужна, т.к. `Все они должны передавать и принимать WCHAR_T*`, а `WCHAR_T*` у вас либо `wchar_t*`, либо `uint16_t*`...

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, так эти оба - он и есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy `wchar_t`, `uint16_t` и `char16_t` это три различных типа. Каст указателя на один тип в  указатель на другой тип и последующее разыменование есть UB, т.к. нарушает strict aliasing.

Comment: Сносим дефайны из вопроса и пишем `#define WCHAR_T char16_t` и всё. А при передаче в уже скомпилированный код ни один из них даже не в курсе, какой тип указан в другом, так что всё должно быть хорошо если они бинарно совместимы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой код возвращает `true`:

```
const wchar_t* wchar_str  = L"йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю"
                            L"ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
                            L"测试中文双字节表示的文本以检查编码"
                            L"テスト用日本語テキスト"
                            L"ტესტი ტექსტი იაპონური ტესტირება";
const char16_t* utf16_str = u"йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю"
                            u"ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ"
                            u"测试中文双字节表示的文本以检查编码"
                            u"テスト用日本語テキスト"
                            u"ტესტი ტექსტი იაპონური ტესტირება";

bool is_equal = true;
while (*wchar_str != L'\0' && *utf16_str != u'\0')
    if (*wchar_str++ != *utf16_str++)
        is_equal = false;

std::clog << "wchar_t and char16_t is equal: "
          << std::boolalpha
          << is_equal
          << std::endl;
```

Других двухбайтовых кодировок, кроме UTF-16, я не нашёл. Видимо, это всегда должно работать корректно.

Comment: [А такой](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcdc71c87e123dd4) возвращает `false`.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, очевидно один из них беззнаковый. Насколько знаю я `-1` используется только для EOF.